# How to force copy to output directory over eveything els?

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, nuget, csproj

I have this code snippet in my `.csproj` file to force a specific version of `System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.dll` to be copied into the output folder, after build:

```
  <Target Name="ForcingUnsafeSpecificVersion" AfterTargets="AfterBuild">
    <Copy SourceFiles="Path\System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.dll" DestinationFolder="$(OutDir)" />
  </Target>
```

But it doesn't work. It doesn't override the version of the output directory, or probably something else is overriding it.

I also tried:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe" Version="4.6.0-preview.18571.3">
      <NoWarn>NU1605</NoWarn>
    </PackageReference>
  </ItemGroup>
```

Still no success. I also tried:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="Path\System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.dll">
      <Link>System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.dll</Link>
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
```

Didn't work. Please note that this line works

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="Path\System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.dll">
      <Link>System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe2.dll</Link>
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
```

If I add number 2 at the end of the name of the output file, then it works. But it seems that all of these build configurations fail and get overridden by something else.

How do I force this file to be copied into the output directory?

Comment: Hi, any update for this issue?

Answer (score 1):

1.It seems you're simply trying to copy something to OutDir after build.

```
  <Target Name="ForcingUnsafeSpecificVersion" AfterTargets="AfterBuild">
    <Copy SourceFiles="Path\System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.dll" DestinationFolder="$(OutDir)" />
  </Target>
```

This task should always work if you just need to copy one file,if not, maybe it could be something about access. You can add a `OverwriteReadOnlyFiles` options to the command to check if it helps:

```
  <Target Name="ForcingUnsafeSpecificVersion" AfterTargets="AfterBuild">
    <Copy SourceFiles="Path\System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.dll" DestinationFolder="$(OutDir)" OverwriteReadOnlyFiles="true"/>
  </Target>
```

2.If it still fails, change the [msbuild verbosity](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/saraford/2008/10/07/did-you-know-you-can-configure-the-msbuild-verbosity-in-the-output-window-329/) to `Detailed` and check the detailed log in Output window:

[image]

You can figure out what happened in that process according to that log.

3.Also, you can try if you can copy one assembly to target path by `copy or xcopy command in cmd.exe`, if it works, then you can also consider using a [Exec Task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/exec-task?view=vs-2019) to do what you want.

4.If all above not helps, please share more details of your project type and the details about the content of the rpoject(nuget packages...). I guess if there's any misunderstanding about the `$(OutDir)`, maybe actually you're trying to copy that to `publish/deploy` folder instead of normal output folder(bin\Debug\netcoreappx.x...).

Comment: The problem was that I had to copy a DLL of a referenced nuget package. And I guess nuget was overriding my file. I ended up adding retry to my task. That solved it.

Comment: Glad to know it has been resolved, you can consider adding it as [self-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) and mark it to help someone with similar issue :) Just a reminder!